# Триггер в соседней базе данных. (ошибка)

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Есть БД [tdb1] и [tdb2]. 
При помощи триггера [trg1] мониторится tdb1 и необходимая информация пишется в таблицу БД [tdb2].
Столкнулся с проблемой:

> сообщение: 916, уровень: 14, состояние: 1, процедура: trg1, строка: 42
>   [строка начала пакета: 2] Серверу-участнику "user_name" не удалось
>   обратиться к базе данных "tdb2" в текущем контексте безопасности.

читал это : [docs.microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-916-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-2017)

Помогло только это:

> ALTER DATABASE tdb1 SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;

Но не совсем понял как это работает и что за собой влечет.

Изначально все писалось в ту же БД где и триггер, проблем не было. Но было принято решение разделить триггер и таблицу в которую он пишет, после чего начались проблемы описанные выше.

Не могу найти решение.

Answer (score 2):

Параметр TRUSTWORTHY явно указывает доверяет ли сервер указанной базе данных. По-умолчанию установлено значение OFF. При установленном значении OFF обращение к объектам вне базы вызовет ошибку.

Зачем это нужно и какой в этом смысл? Когда пользователи работают на каком-либо конкретном сервере, у них есть конкретные права, которые соответственно разрешают/запрещают доступ к объектам баз данных. Но вот кто-то захотел получить несанкционированный доступ. Этот злоумышленник может установить сервер баз данных (на нем он sysadmin), создать некую базу, в базе создать код, который позволит обратиться к запрещенным объектам. Затем, после восстановления этой БД на "рабочем" сервере, он получит доступ к объектам баз данных в обход локальной политики безопасности сервера.

Вот здесь и срабатывает TRUSTWORTHY, нельзя восстановить произвольную БД на сервере и сразу получить из нее доступ к объектам других БД.

Comment: т.е. без этого параметра никак не обойтись, чтобы обратиться к объекту соседней бд?

Comment: Можно обойтись, гуглите "cross database ownership chaining", но там любая восстановленная/присоединенная база может порушить всю политику безопасности

Answer (score 1):

> Но не совсем понял как это работает и что за собой влечет.

Могу порекомендовать статью (на английском) в трёх частях ([ссылка](https://sqlity.net/en/1653/the-trustworthy-database-property-explained-part-1/) на 1-ю часть), где детально рассматривается влияние параметра `TRUSTWORTHY`. Если БД с включённым `TRUSTWORTHY` спроектирована недостаточно тщательно, то, при некоторых условиях, через такую БД становится возможным атака на инстанс SqlServer. Если вы контролируете инстанс, то использование `TRUSTWORTHY` на вашей совести. Вдобавок, проблемы могут возникнуть, если, например, вы проектируете БД, которая потом будет публиковаться на какой-либо инстанс, который вы не контролируете (здравомыслящий админ инстанса вряд ли разрешит включение `TRUSTWORTHY` на сторонней БД).

> Не могу найти решение.

При работе с одной БД всё просто. Обычно есть какой-то логин для доступа к инстансу

```
USE [master];
GO
CREATE LOGIN [SomeLogin] WITH PASSWORD = N'************';
GO
```

С логином, как правило, связан пользователь в конкретной БД

```
USE [db1];
GO
CREATE USER [User1] FOR LOGIN [SomeLogin];
GO
```

у которого есть какие-то права на объекты этой БД (выданные напрямую, или приобретённые через членство в ролях).

Если код, инициирующий срабатывание триггера, выполняется в контексте логина `[SomeLogin]`, то при обращении из триггера ко второй БД у этого логина должен быть к ней доступ.

Соответственно, создайте пользователя, связанного с логином, во второй БД

```
USE [db2];
GO
CREATE USER [User2] FOR LOGIN [SomeLogin];
GO
```

и выдайте ему права, чтобы он мог писать в соответствующую таблицу.